# error deleting from database

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL Server Compact database created through VS 2010 (Local Database File option).
On form load (`CategoryForm`) I load the values from the database into the `DataGridView1`. I also add an extra `ButtonColumn` programmatically that I use for the `Delete` part. 
The problem is this:

- On initial form load, the first time I press delete on any row, it works. If i press it again it does not work.
- The second time i click the button, the printed text I get on my `Msgbox`, is the Text of button! (delete) (screenshot included) p.s As mentionted below, when I comment-out the extra stuff, I get the correct values returned.

What I tried:

- Commented out everything SQL-related, left only the part where I get the `RowIndex` and the value at the specific cell at that index. I print them both on `MsgBox`. The values I get are correct. For example, `0` index and value `test` for first row with text `test`.

Below is my progress as well as screenshots:

`CellContentClick` method:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContectClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    Dim i As String

    'If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    'If e.RowIndex >= 0 And e.RowIndex <= DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 Then

    i = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value.ToString
    MsgBox(e.RowIndex)
    MsgBox(i)
    SQLStringDelete = "DELETE FROM Category WHERE categoryname = '" & i & "'"
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
    SQLConn.Open() 'Open the connection
    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
    SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStringDelete 'Sets the SQL String
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 'Executes SQL Command

    'Create Adapter
    Dim DataAdapter As SqlCeDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT categoryname FROM Category", SQLConn)
    'Create DataSet
    Dim Dataset As New DataSet
    'fill the datset
    DataAdapter.Fill(Dataset)
    'attach dataset to the datagrid
    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = Dataset.Tables(0)
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = ""
        .Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End With

    DataAdapter = Nothing
    Dataset = Nothing

    SQLConn.Close() 'Close the connection



End Sub
```

`Form_Load` method:

```
 Private Sub CategoryForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString 'Set the Connection String
        SQLConn.Open() 'Open the connection

        'Create Adapter
        Dim DataAdapter As SqlCeDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT categoryname FROM Category", SQLConn)
        'Create DataSet
        Dim Dataset As New DataSet
        'fill the datset
        DataAdapter.Fill(Dataset)
        'attach dataset to the datagrid
        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = Dataset.Tables(0)
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = ""
            .Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        End With

        DataAdapter = Nothing
        Dataset = Nothing
        SQLConn.Close()

        With buttonColumn
            .Name = "DeleteButtonColumn"
            .HeaderText = ""
            .Text = "Delete"
            .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
            .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
            .Width = 50
        End With

        If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(buttonColumn)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Screenshots:

[image: Button text returned instead of cell value]

[image: Still there after several click :)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the columns where autoregenerating causing column re-arrangement on each the second click. Just set `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false` in both the form load and event and it works.